# Apache Camel, routes added don't throw OnException

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, apache-camel

I am writing from the Camel and Spring world!

I am adding routes programmatically using this [recipe](http://camel.apache.org/loading-routes-from-xml-files.html).

Basically you get the camel context and add your routes using a file.

This is the issue:
The routes added at runtime don't trigger any `OnException`, set on the context file read by Spring.

To recap:

1. I have a spring context file that looks like:

```xml
<camel:camelContext>
    <onException id="exceptions">
     <handled>
        <constant>true</constant>
      </handled>
      <process ref="logExceptionProcessor"/>
      <to uri="activemq:adapterLOG"/>
      <process ref="mailSender"/>
    </onException>
    ...
```

2. After I've added my route getting the camel context, that added route doesn't throw the `OnException` set.

Do you have any advice on this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

There are two different scopes for error handlers you can use.  The first is a route level error handler which will manage error handling for just that route and the second is global error handling for everything in that context.  If you want to get a few more details go to the "scopes" section in the documentation.

```
http://camel.apache.org/error-handler.html
```

For your use case when loading in the routes you won't be able to leverage a global error handler because the route definition is created separate from the context and then added to it at runtime.  Meaning you will need to have error handling defined for every route you load separately.  NOTE:  That does not mean you can't create your own common error handling policy and have each of your routes reference that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it can't be done :) : 
"When adding routes as shown on this page, the routes is isolated and cannot re-use any existing onException, intercept etc." From http://camel.apache.org/loading-routes-from-xml-files.html